# Recursive Incrementer

Tags: c, recursion

I'm writing a recursive function that takes a char array, which represents a number, and a pointer to a digit in that array.  The point of the function is to increment the number just like the ++ operator.  However, when I try it out on the number '819'.  It doesn't increment it to '820' but instead changes it to '810' (it increments the last digit but doesn't do the recursion that I want).  Can someone help me out with this?  Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* inc(char *num, char* p)
{   
    if( *p>='0' && *p<='8' )
    {
        *p++;
    }
    else if ( *p=='9' )
    {
        *p = '0';
        inc(num, --p);
    }

    return num;
}

main()
{
    char x[] = "819";

    printf("%s\n", inc(x, x+strlen(x)-1) ); //pass the number and a pointer to the last digit
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `*p++ to (*p)++` ; You want to increment the number contained in p.

```
   char* inc(char *num, char* p)
    {   
        if( *p>='0' && *p<='8' )
        {
            (*p)++;       //==> change
        }
        else if ( *p=='9' )
        {
            *p = '0';
            inc(num, --p);
        }

        return num;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

`++` operator has higher precedence over `*` . Hence,

```
*p++ ==> *p then p++; // p's value before the increment.
```

Refer the precedence table [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

Comment: I thought that *p++ would return *p's value before p is actually incremented?

Comment: Your edit is wrong. I mean your precedence statement is right but you don't take into account that the post-increment is delayed until the end of the statement.

Comment: I have split the code bit too much. I have edited the same. @Pax, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's because `*p++` retrieves the character then increments the *pointer*. You want `(*p)++` which increments the character at that pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *inc (char *num, char* p) {
    if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '8') {
        (*p)++;
    } else if (*p == '9') {
        *p = '0';
        inc(num, --p);
    }
    return num;
}
```

You should be very careful on running this on strings above 9xxx since you'll have to ensure you've left room for the next digit up (pre-fill it with 0 if necessary). Otherwise add protection such as the wrap feature below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *inc (char *num, char* p) {
    if (p < num)
        return num;
    if ((*p < '0') || (*p > '9'))
        return num;
    if (*p < '9') {
        (*p)++;
        return num;
    }
    *p = '0';
    return inc(num, --p);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char x[] = "819";
    char y[] = "8999";
    char z[] = "9999";
    char a[] = "aaa72";
    char b[] = "aaa279";
    char c[] = "aaa9999";
    printf("%s\n", inc(x, x+strlen(x)-1) );
    printf("%s\n", inc(y, y+strlen(y)-1) );
    printf("%s\n", inc(z, z+strlen(z)-1) );
    printf("%s\n", inc(a, a+strlen(a)-1) );
    printf("%s\n", inc(b, b+strlen(b)-1) );
    printf("%s\n", inc(c, c+strlen(c)-1) );
    return 0;
}
```

This code results in:

```
820
9000
0000
aaa73
aaa280
aaa0000
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I always follow some guidelines that help achieving correctness when coding in C++:

- **Do not modify and get the value of
  anything in the same instruction.**
  i.e. `inc(num, --p);` is banned
  because the second argument of inc is
  not const.
- **Never dereference a
  pointer and do something with it in
  the same line.** i.e. All forms of
  `(*p)++;` are banned.
- Always **guarantee const-correctness in function parameters**.
- **Command/query separation**: Functions should generally either be const or void.
- **Do not use
  recursion** if you can avoid it i.e. always look for a non-recursive alternative first. (This question is an example in which you can avoid it).
- **Design by Contract.** Add preconditions to the
  beginning, and postconditions to the
  end of your functions.

Applying them to your function may help to remove bugs in it.

Comment: That's good advice for safety, but unnecessary for those of us who have been using C so long that the precedence rules are accessible from the neurons in the spinal cord without ever having to trouble the brain :-) I've only just recently forgotten the Wordstar 3.3 exit command from my MSDOS 2.11 days and I expect the neurons containing vi commands will be the last to decay from my rotting corpse. On a serious note, I disagree vehemently with not using recursion although not enough to downvote - it's often the most elegant solution.

Comment: I wasn't born an extremist :) I learnt this advice the hard way, probably because throughout my career the code I've had to maintain wasn't written by those of you who have been using C so long that the precedence rules are accessible from the neurons in the spinal cord without ever having to trouble the brain. (Worse, some of them seemed to _think_ that they knew what they were doing - they didn't, actually.)

Comment: Recursion is an absolutely essential tool for solving many everyday problems in a natural and simple manner - banning it out of hand is ridiculous!

Comment: @Neil: I edited my guideline to say "always look for alternatives". I don't remember the last time I used recursion. However, my guideline is, if you have to use it, then you'd better use a simple algorithm and it'd better work well - don't just use it and then come asking me why it doesn't work. If you use it, do it in a way as simple as possible. Again, this comes from experience. Again, maybe some great developers can use it without messing things up. As always, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the side-effect of the original program as compiled on gcc, (This side-effect doesn't happen on @Pax program)

```
int
 main()
{
char x[] = "9";
char z[] = {57,57,57,57};

int t=0;
for(t=0;t<4;++t)
    printf("z == %d\n",z[t]);

inc(x, x+strlen(x)-1);

for(t=0;t<4;++t)
    printf("z == %d\n",z[t]);
```

}

output:
     z == 57
     z == 57
     z == 57
     z == 57
     z == 48
     z == 48
     z == 48
     z == 48